# Proving that $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is open at $\text{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and that its tangent space is isomorphic to $\text{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces

[image]

Hello. The image corresponds to chapter 8 of vector fields of the book introduction to the smooth manifolds of the author Lee.

**Question 1**. Why $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is an open set of the vector space $\text{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$?

**Question 2.** Why its tangent space is naturally isomorphic to $\text{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For 1, $\text{det}:\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ is continuous then $\text{det}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus 0)$ is open and  $\text{det}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus 0)=\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ but for 2, I don't know

Comment: So you are done with 1. For 2., see Proposition 3.13 in Lee.

Comment: but the Proposition 3.13 gives that $T_{I_n}\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ but not to $\text{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$

Comment: No. $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ is not even a vector space.

Comment: Ar okay. Read also proposition 3.9

Comment: I see. $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ open submanifold of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ then $T_{I_n}\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R}))$ is identified with $M(n,\mathbb{R})$